# Linq query to filter on most recent value / record

Tags: c#, linq

I have a 'complex' linq query I would like to improve and to understand.

```
(from x in tblOrder
 orderby x.OrderNo  
 // where x.Filename is most recent filename for this order
 group x by new { x.OrderNo, x.Color } into groupedByColorCode
 select new
 {
     OrderNo = groupedByColorCode.Key.OrderNo,
     ProductRef = groupedByColorCode.FirstOrDefault().ProductRef,
     Color = groupedByColorCode.Key.Color,
     Packing = groupedByColorCode.FirstOrDefault().Packing,
     TotalQuantity = groupedByColorCode.Sum(bcc => bcc.OriQty).ToString()
 }
```

x is an Order. I also would like to filter by Filename. Filename is a variable from tblOrder. Actually I would like to keep and keep only the orders from the most recent file.

What 'where' clause should I add to my linq query to be able to filter these last file name.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear what do you mean about _last filename_. There is _LastOrDefault()_ method in Linq if you need last record.

Comment: Or there is _MaxBy()_ or _MinBy()_ if you need max or min by some criteria.

Comment: Thank you. You see my question is clear :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** it's better to use *orderby* in the end of the query, because sorting will work quicker on the smaller set of data.

**Second** you should use *where* in the top of query, it will make smaller your set before grouping and sorting (set it after *from* line)

**At last** *grouping* creates dictionary with *Key* = `new { x.OrderNo, x.Color }` (in this keys) and *Value* = *IEnumerable*, and then *groupedByColorCode* becomes *IEnumerabler* of *{Key, Value}*. So it should stand in the end before *orederby*

Answer (score 0):

there is MaxBy() or MinBy() if you need max or min by some criteria